# How to get all of the errors logged to the console of developer tools?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to collect a list of all errors in my webpage (or atleast all errors logged as errors to the console log).

I understand that window.onerror will log my script errors.  It also mentions:

> "Note that some/many error events do not trigger window.onerror, you have to listen for them specifically. "

I've noticed some errors don't trigger the window.onerror.  How would I listen for them "specifically?" (or atleast log the maximum amount of errors possible)

Here is an HTML with a file not found error that won't be caught by window.onerror:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    var gOldOnError = window.onerror;
    window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
      alert("Found an error!");
      return false;
    };
    //window.zz.ff.ee.zz;  if I uncomment this I get an alert as expected.

    </script>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Simple Example of a file that has an errors</title>  
    <script src='filethatdoesntexist.html'></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using `try/catch` blocks and use `console.error(catched exception)` inside catch block to show all errors